# SharePoint two tier fault-tolerant

Tags: 2013, installation, server-farm, architecture

The time has come to install SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, but before I do I would like a 2nd opinion.

My current plan is to have 4 servers - two SQL configured with AlwaysOn AG and 2 load balanced WFE with all application services.

We will only have 200 users, so I'm hoping that this configuration will be enough. Does anyone have experience with this? Would it be better to only load balance certain services, and then split the others between the two WFEs? I.e. have search on one, excel web services on another, MMD on both, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 200 Users this configuration more than enough. I am guessing you have enough memory to run all services and web apps.

I would configure Search on one server, and User Profile Services on 2nd server.

Distributed Cache on both servers.

You may also need the Workflow manager as well.

I wish if you have another server which will be your Application server. Why i said this, If you have tons of content and search services will consume too much resources, so try to minimize load on WFE.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj219591(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

We have 2.000 users with 2 WFE, 1 Application Server + 1 Web App server. Your configuration is more than enough.